# Check if data exist in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, union

I have two table containing login credentials for users.

One table contain credentials for admin users, and another table contain non-admin users. Admin and non admin users uses the same login page. When a user log in, I need to check if user is an admin user or non admin user to show the correct / relevant content.

I have tried numerous queries but am not able to do so.

Here is my latest code I found on STackoverflow but shows no results with a syntax error:

```
SELECT TOP 1 from
(
 SELECT aes_decrypt(NonAdminEmail, 'SALT') as email from NonAdminUsers     WHERE aes_decrypt(NonAdminEmail, 'SALT') = 'email@domain'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT aes_decrypt(Admin_Email, 'SALT') as email from AdminUsers WHERE     aes_decrypt(Admin_Email, 'SALT') = 'demail@domain'
) a
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(NonAdminEmail, 'SALT') as User, password 
FROM NonAdminUsers 
WHERE  aes_decrypt(NonAdminEmail, 'SALT') ='$username' AND password='$password' 
UNION 
SELECT aes_decrypt(Admin_Email, 'SALT') as User, password 
FROM AdminUsers 
WHERE username='email@domain.com' AND password='$password
```

**EDIT:**

Outline of the tables are like this:

NonAdmin

```
NonAdmin_ID   Password        NonAdminEmail     

001           pass3           email1@domain.com       
001           pass5           email2@domain.com
003           pass2           email3@domain.com
```

AdminUsers

```
AdminUserID   Pass            AdminEmail

A001           Apass1         adminemail1@domain
A002           Apass2         adminemail2@domain
A003           Apass3         adminemail3@domain
```

I want to check if the email and password combination is in either of the tables

Comment: In your 1st query you use TOP which does  not work for MySql, this is why you get a syntax error. Post sample data of the 2 tables, expected results and clarify what you want.

Comment: are you sure that the username is encryoted and not the password?

Comment: @nbk passwords are hashed in the actual code

Comment: @forpas I added sample data as requested. I want to check if the email and password combination is in either of the tables.

Comment: `'$username'` is a string containing the characters $, u, s, e, r, etc., unless you are using some programming language on this that converts the string before sending it to the DBMS.

Comment: And the username is an email address (`username='email@domain.com'`)? The column names in your queries don't match the column names in your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check if user is an admin user or non admin user to show the
>   correct / relevant content

Use `EXISTS`:

```
select
  case
    when exists (
      select 1 from AdminUsers 
      where aes_decrypt(AdminEmail, 'SALT') = '?' and Pass = '?'
    ) then 'Admin'
    when exists (
      select 1 from NonAdmin 
      where aes_decrypt(NonAdminEmail, 'SALT') = '?' and Password = '?'
    ) then 'Non Admin'
    else 'Unknown'
  end result
```

Replace `'?'` with the values that you want to check.

Comment: Great thanks. It there a way to use the email address and password as variables for log in? I would love to use the email as a variable to query alternative info from the DB after successful login?

Comment: I guess you already have the email address and password for this code to work, in php code maybe, because you compare them against the values in the tables.

Comment: HAHA. Blonde moment there. Many thanks for the help